# How can I export PrimeFaces line chart into a pdf file?

Tags: primefaces

I have a page with a `<p:chart type="line">`. I need to export its content into a PDF file. How could I achieve it?

Comment: You can't do this with PrimeFaces... Sounds like you need a 'report generator'. Look at one, e.g. Jasper Reports, and use that.

Comment: Check out this tutorial: http://blog.hatemalimam.com/export-primefaces-charts-to-pdf/